# 12.04 Keystone charm fails to deploy: How do I debug it?

Tags: juju, maas

I have a MaaS setup and on top of that I'm trying deploying openstack, following the video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2H3fat0K5w

The problem I am having is that the keystone charm keeps saying that there is an install error. I have no idea where to look and see what went wrong.

Where should I start on trying to figure out what is not working? Is there a log or anything I can look at?

I'm using 12.04 for the MaaS server and the MaaS nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the answer to this in our [debugging hooks](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/authors-hook-debug.html#intercept-install) section of the docs.

What you'll need to do is launch debug-hooks from the Juju client machine, then resolve the error with the `--retry` flag (or retry from the Juju Gui if you are using it). This will re-execute the hook and trap the event in the debug-hooks window. From there you will be in the right directory to run the hook file by typing `hooks/<name-of-failed-hook>` to get output. When you are done, simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> to exit the terminal and signal to Juju that the hook is finished executing.

(Taken from [another answer to really the same problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362687/juju-debug-hooks-how-to-run-hook-in-debug-terminal-or-get-more-information/362733#362733)).