# Juju debug-hooks, how to run hook in debug terminal or get more information?

Tags: juju, openstack, debugging

I'm having trouble deploying the Havana Openstack charms on precise for cinder, nova-cloud-controller, and quantum-gateway. I'm using MaaS running Virsh managed KVM machines.

I'm getting errors with the install hooks.

I read that you can use `juju debug-hooks` to try to find the problem, but that you basically get given a terminal to the machine so you can do whatever the hook would have done by hand. I've seen a blog post that said you could run a command in the terminal to run the hook. I'd just like to get some more visibility on what is failing, so I am thinking that if I can run the hook in the terminal, I might see output that tells me what is happening.

How can I manually trigger a hook in a debug-hooks terminal? Or is there a better way to find what is causing a charm to fail to deploy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the answer to this in our [debugging hooks](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/authors-hook-debug.html#intercept-install) section of the docs.

What you'll need to do is launch debug-hooks from the Juju client machine, then resolve the error with the `--retry` flag (or retry from the Juju Gui if you are using it). This will re-execute the hook and trap the event in the debug-hooks window. From there you will be in the right directory to run the hook file by typing `hooks/<name-of-failed-hook>` to get output. When you are done, simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> to exit the terminal and signal to Juju that the hook is finished executing.

Answer (score 1):

As all of your charms failed to install, I'd check out the contents of /var/log/juju on each of the failed service units; you can ssh to them using juju:

```
juju ssh nova-cloud-controller/0
```

Looking at the log contents should tell you what's up; as you are deploying OpenStack Havana from the Cloud Archive for Ubuntu 12.04, I would suspect that your servers can't access ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com - either directly or via squid-deb-proxy if you are using that feature on your MAAS server.