# What are the steps to deploy OpenStack in a VM using juju?

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I'm looking for a guide to deploy OpenStack (all in one) in a small VM (2 cores, 2GB ram) for development purposes, as well as for learning the juju process.

1. What environment should I choose?

   - "maas"?
   - "local"?
2. If I choose "maas" - while bootstrapping, I get ERROR 409 Conflict - why? I've setup the mass-cli login, using the profile "maas" as instructed.

   - Do I need to add additional nodes?
   - Can I add the node on which maas is already installed?
   - Do I execute juju commands from the machine being the original "maas" machine?
3. I've tried using juju-gui in a "local" environment. I've followed the video from youtube on deploying openstack using juju, some of the components failed to install, their progress bars turned red - why?
4. Where can I find the list of juju commands to deploy a single all in one node?

   - When deploying from commandline, how can I verify the installation's progress/status? watch juju status seems a bit uninformative for first time user.

   [image: Typical MAAS Installation]
5. Considering the above picture :

   - Is there a single OpenStack deployment spanning across multiple clusters? Or is there a single OpenStack deployment per cluster?

Comment: If you are wondering why you don't get an answer please read [this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7664/169736). People usually hunt down questions they can answer and if they can't fully answer a question they will back off. BTW, your first question is too subjective, I wouldn't ask it

Comment: The first question isn't subjective. It's a legitimate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. *What environment should I choose? - "maas"? - "local"?*

   Local is faster and more lightweight because you are not doing virtualization but using Linux Containers (LXC). I would try it first. I tried it and ran in to some problems where the LXC container was not allowed to build some kernel modules for Quantum/Neutron networking, but Quantum/Neutron networking is optional, so LXC may work for you.

   MaaS is designed to manage machines (usually physical, not virtual ones, but you can do virtual ones). Because of this, if you use MaaS, you will have to make a machine (possibly virtual) act as the MaaS server, and then network other machines (again, possibly virtual) to it. I've tried doing this before with KVM virtualized machines, and if you are doing it with very many things deployed, you need a lot of RAM.
2. *If I choose "maas":*

   - *while bootstrapping, I get ERROR 409 Conflict - why?*

     409 Conflict is a general error that means there was some reason MaaS could not complete your request. There could be a lot of reasons this is happening, see the rest of my answers to see if anything starts to stick out as a possible cause.
   - *I've setup the mass-cli login, using the profile "maas" as instructed. Do I need to add additional nodes?*

     To deploy anything with MaaS, you will need to add machines to the MaaS cluster (other than the MaaS server itself -- so you very well may have to create more virtual machines).
   - *Can I add the node on which maas is already installed? - Do I execute juju commands from the machine being the original "maas" machine?*

     You get an API key from the account page in the MaaS web UI and put that in your `.juju/environments.yaml` juju configuration file along with the network address of the juju server. That allows whatever machine the juju client is running on to login to the MaaS server and send it commands. To get the key to use, go to the MaaS server web interface (`http://ip_of_maas_server/MAAS/`) click on the username in the upper right and then click on preferences on the menu that appears. That page will list a key to use.
3. *I've tried using juju-gui in a "local" environment. I've followed the video from youtube on deploying openstack using juju, some of the components failed to install, their progress bars turned red - why?*

   It is hard to say for sure without more information -- the bar turning red means that some part of the code that set up the machine juju is using experienced an error for some reason. See [Juju debug-hooks, how to run hook in debug terminal or get more information?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362687/juju-debug-hooks-how-to-run-hook-in-debug-terminal-or-get-more-information) for information on how you can get more information about the specific error.
4. *Where can I find the list of juju commands to deploy a single all in one node?*

   The juju team has been working on bundles that let you deploy more that one service with a single command. I did see what looked like support for this in the WebGUI, in the form of an option to export and import a group of services. I don't know how ready this is (and you would need an export of a working configuration for openstack).

   - *When deploying from commandline, how can I verify the installation's progress/status? `watch juju status` seems a bit uninformative for first time user.*

     Running `juju debug-log` would be one way, but that can be (quite) verbose.
5. *Considering the above picture : - Is there a single OpenStack deployment spanning across multiple clusters? Or is there a single OpenStack deployment per cluster?*

   That picture doesn't necessarily show anything directly having to do with openstack. It shows how you can configure MaaS. I will note that in a testing case, it is possible and quite likely to have one region controller and one cluster instead of one region with two clusters. A cluster is simply a group of servers (usually physical, but could be virtual) on the same switch that MaaS will manage and deploy juju services on. MaaS is not specific to Openstack -- you can deploy any Juju charm on top of it. So, you could have a cluster with a few machines managed by MaaS, and then use Juju to deploy wordpress and MySQL. MaaS would turn on two of the machines it manages at Juju's request, install Ubuntu on them, and then let Juju configure a webserver with Wordpress on one of the physical machines and a MySQL database server on the other. If you were to add another Unit to the MySQL service in Juju, Juju would have MaaS start yet another machine and it would install Ubuntu on that machine and then configure MySQL on that machine. In an openstack setup, Juju is just configuring the openstack software on the machines that MaaS manages. In a production, high availability setup, it would be prudent to create at least two MaaS clusters, and split up the units for each openstack service across those clusters so if you had trouble with one MaaS cluster the Openstack units in the other cluster would take over and the openstack system would continue to run without interruption.